# Wi-Fi very slow in Ubuntu 16.04 (Qualcomm Atheros)

Tags: wireless, acer, atheros

I have Acer Aspire E 15 and my Wifi is working, but very slow (sometimes I cannot send e-mails).

I have tried few solutions from the internet, but nothing is working.

Result of lspci:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042]    (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

I get the following messages:

```
dmesg | grep ath
[    2.161286] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.403955] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.836854] audit: type=1400 audit(1474185834.396:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=672 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.300258] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 11ad:0806) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[    4.300268] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    4.302158] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    4.302161] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    4.302163] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    4.302164] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[    4.312729] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   11.072137] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[   11.072139] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   11.072140] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   11.072141] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[   11.072142] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[   11.072143] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[   11.072144] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
```

The solution with backports is unfortunately not working :(

Unfortunately, I don't understand a thing from the above messages. Could you give me a hint how to solve this?

I'm using Ubuntu since 2004 and can fix some small issues, but I have never had problems with WiFi :(

Comment: I have seen alot of posts regarding upgrading atheros wifi driver. I would recommend a google search and look into how to update it. Since I don't have one myself I can't test them. But look into it, should not be that hard :)